# Match specific word at the beginning or in the middle of string in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp:

```
[^\w]delete[^\w]
```

The objective is to match the exact word `delete` in a string (if `delete` is between special characters then there's a match as well). The regexp works fine, however when the word `delete` is at the beginning of the string, there's no match when it should.

I tried changing the rexexp to

```
[^\w]*delete[^\w]
```

The result is that it can detect `delete` at the beginning of the string, however it also matches `Xdelete` when it should not.

Any ideas how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching `delete` if between non word characters or between word boundaries:

```
\bdelete\b
```

## Demo

Comment: Just a question, Tim. Why can't we simply write `\bdelete\b`? [Link](https://regex101.com/r/ic01h7/1)